# Can't solve error with reactivity in nuxt3 and pinia

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-8, pinia, nuxt3

How to get result in template ? Pls

I have a function that should display the name of the template

```
<script setup>
const { $userStore, $generalStore, $forumStore } = useNuxtApp()
import {storeToRefs} from "pinia";
const { title, body } = storeToRefs($forumStore)
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const categoryId = route.params.id
    posts.value = await $forumStore.getPosts(categoryId)
    console.log(posts.value)
  } catch (error) {
    if (error ) {

    } console.log(error)
  }
})
</script>
```

here is the template

```
  <div>
    <h1>Posts in Category: {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>
    <ul v-if="posts && posts.length > 0" >
      <li v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
        {{ post.title }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

here is the ***console.log(posts.value)*** my posts array from server

[image]

nothing happens nothing happens please help

Comment: Where are you defining 'posts' as a ref or reactive?

Comment: Pass the result in *variable* and use it. Ex: ```let data = []; this.data = posts.value;```. Then in your view  ```<li v-for="post in data" :key="post.id">```

Answer (score 0):

Yes WillC
, you are right, I messed up something with reactivity. Now my code is working

***my pinia store***

```
export const useForumStore = defineStore('forum', {
 id: 'post',
    state: () => ({
    }),
    actions: {
        setPosts(posts) {
            this.posts = posts;
        },
    }
})
```

***my component template***

```
  <div>
    <h1>Posts in Category: {{ $route.params.id }}</h1>
    <ul v-if="$forumStore.posts.length">
      <li v-for="post in $forumStore.posts" :key="post.id">
        {{ post.title }} {{ post.body }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

***and script***

```
onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const categoryId = route.params.id;
    let res = await $axios.get(`/api/categories/${categoryId}/posts`)
    postRef.value = res.data;
    $forumStore.setPosts(postRef.value.posts);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});
```

I think that you would have done better, but for me at this stage it's ok))